# Tortoise SVN - How to Merge Changes in Branch and Trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a Branch version that is a number of months old. In the meantime the Trunk has also seen a number of changes.

How do I merge the 2 together without losing any updates? Do I merge the Trunk to the Branch first, and then merge Branch back into the Trunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either merge direction will work fine. But, if the branch and trunk have diverged significantly in the past few months, then the merge will be difficult.

The normal advice to merge from trunk to branch, is to do that *frequently* as you develop the branch, so that the final merge from branch back to trunk is easy to accomplish. Since you have not done that, you are stuck with a big merge either way.

You cannot lose data from the merge, as long as you have committed all your current changes. A merge is a working-copy operation. You have the responsibility to check the merge prior to committing the result. If the merge is bad, or too complicated for a single big merge, then you can revert changes in your working copy and start over.

The main advantage of merging trunk to branch, at this point, is that you can compile, test, and maybe peer review the result of the merge on your branch before committing it to trunk.

The main advantage of merging branch to trunk, at this point, is that this is the eventual goal state anyway, so you may save yourself some work.

The rest is up to you, unless the team you are working on has a standard method of merging you must follow.